# How can I create a Derby database conditionally on deploy time?

Tags: spring-mvc, derby

In a Java configured Spring MVC (4.0.1) project I'd like to use Hibernate (4.3.x). I use NetBEans 8.2, Java SE 8, Java EE 7. When I try to deploy the project on Glassfish 5.0 server, the error message says:

`Exception while preparing the app : Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [create table YYYY (id integer generated by default as identity, ..., primary key (id))]
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Table/View 'YYY' already exists in Schema 'APP'`.

I understand its reason. The previous deployment created the database. But how can I configure the Spring EntityManagerFactiryBean/DataSourceBean to create the DB just in case it does not exist?

The current persistence configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig
{
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
  {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"); 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    factory.setDataSource(this.springJpaDataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("XxxPU");
    factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource springJpaDataSource()
  {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost/xxx");
    dataSource.setUsername("app");
    dataSource.setPassword("app");
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager()
  {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(
    entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
  }
}
```

I renamed the `persistence.xml` to avoid any side effect.

Because I didn't get any useable answer I had to change the db properties from:

`properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");`

To

`properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "none");`

after the first deployment for the further ones could be success.

Answer (score 1):

Database initialization is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

I believe that you would need to specify:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`